# How to write to next column when running a loop?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to extract all links from a folder in google drive and write two columns, one containing the link, and the next column containing the file name.

I'm new to google scripting and wrote this code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var c=s.getActiveCell();
  var fldr=DriveApp.getFolderById("0B37vVx5p-eGMTmJmTF9JOUwxZnc");
  var files=fldr.getFiles();
  var names=[],f,str;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    f=files.next();
    str='=hyperlink("' + f.getUrl() + '")';
    names.push([str]);
  }
  s.getRange(c.getRow(),c.getColumn(),names.length).setFormulas(names);
}
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var c=s.getActiveCell();
  var fldr=DriveApp.getFolderById("0B37vVx5p-eGMTmJmTF9JOUwxZnc");
  var files=fldr.getFiles();
  var names=[],f,str;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    f=files.next();
    str='=" + f.getName() + "';
    names.push([str]);
  }
  s.getRange(c.getRow(),c.getColumn(),names.length).setFormulas(names);
}
```

The problem is that after writing the links in the first column, it overwrites it with the names in the first column. How can I specify what column the second piece of code should be written to?

Answer (score 1):

There's no real reason to grab these in separate functions, you could just push them both to the same array then insert into the sheet, the code below should do what you're expecting:

```
function getFolders() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var c=s.getActiveCell();
  var fldr=DriveApp.getFolderById("0B37vVx5p-eGMTmJmTF9JOUwxZnc");
  var files=fldr.getFiles();
  var names=[],f,url,name;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    f=files.next();
    url='=hyperlink("' + f.getUrl() + '")';
    name='="' + f.getName() + '"';
    names.push([url,name]);
  }
  s.getRange(c.getRow(),c.getColumn(),names.length, 2).setFormulas(names);
}
```

I had to tweak `name='="' + f.getName() + '"';` because the quotes weren't quite in the right place, it was pushing that string itself to the array rather than the filename.

Pushing both of the values to the array like this means you don't need to offset the range because the array will span 2 columns when you use `setValues()`, hence why I had to add 2 for `numColumns` in the `setValues()` too.

Answer (score 0):

On a Google Apps Script project each function should have unique names otherwise only the last function in the order that they are loaded at execution time will be executed. So, in first place, the hyperlink formulas aren't never written.

By the other hand, as was mentioned on [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56252788/1595451), there is no need to have separate functions to write on each column, one single function could fill both columns at the same time.

On this code line:

```
names.push([str]);
```

The argument por `push` is an array having a single value. Replace this argument by an array incluiding the values for both columns. To make the minimum changes to you first function, rename the `str` variable, add a second code line for the second column with a proper and unique variable name , i.e. (as was shown on the previous answer):

```
url='=hyperlink("' + f.getUrl() + '")';
name='=" + f.getName() + "';
names.push([url,name]);
```

And lastly, add the number of columns to the last statement

```
s.getRange(c.getRow(),c.getColumn(),names.length, 2).setFormulas(names);
```

Don't forget to delete the second function named `myFunction`

Answer (score -1):

Use [`Range.offset`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer)):

> Returns a new range that is offset from this range by the given number of rows and columns (which can be negative). The new range is the same size as the original range.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Google Apps Script, but I'd imagine a loop where you iterate over your file list and increment the offset by one for each file.